# react-admin translate defaultValue for input field

Tags: react-admin

I would like to define default values for the creation view as described [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#default-values). Also I want to have the default values translated as described [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html#translating-your-own-components). I imported the high order component and tried to use translate as a function.

```
import { translate } from 'react-admin';

export const PostCreate = (props) => (
<Create {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput source="title" defaultValue={translate('resources.posts.defaultTitle')} />        
    </SimpleForm>
</Create> );
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Maybe this is a missing feature? The label attribute for example gets translated automatically.

Comment: In order to understand your issue, can you provide more code?
For example, show the whole file, with all imports. Perhaps a working codesandbox which have the same error: https://codesandbox.io/s/pw74xww3p0

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was very busy this week. Thank you for your interest and the link - I thought I'd have to create everything from scratch.. 
Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/q84jz88j94
The error appears as soon as you try to create a new posts. I only changed the /src/posts/PostCreate.js and /src/i18n/en.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `translate` function exported by react-admin is an [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

```
import { translate } from 'react-admin';

const PostCreateView = ({ translate, ...props }) => (
<Create {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput source="title" defaultValue={translate('resources.posts.defaultTitle')} />        
    </SimpleForm>
</Create> );

const PostCreate = translate(PostCreateView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does the `resources` variable comes from? I don't see it imported in your example.

Or maybe, the argument of `translate` must be a string.
Have you tried with something like:

```
translate('resources.posts.defaultTitle')
```

Your approach doesn't seem incorrect. That said, I'm not aware that  `resources.posts.defaultTitle` is exposed by the default translation API of React Admin.

Do not forget to declare your custom translations:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import englishMessages from 'ra-language-english';
import frenchMessages from 'ra-language-french';

const customMessages = {
    fr: {}, // custom french
    en: {}, // custom english
};   

const messages = {
    fr: frenchMessages,
    en: englishMessages,
};
const i18nProvider = locale => { ...messages[locale], ...customMessages[locale] };

const App = () => (
    <Admin locale={resolveBrowserLocale()} i18nProvider={i18nProvider}>
        ...
    </Admin>
);
```

Comment: The quotes got lost when I prepared the code-snippet. Without the quotes it's a un def.
For other cases my custom translations work fine, for example the translation of radio button choices: 

`const choicesInvoiceType = [
    { id: "incoming", name: "resources.invoices.types.incoming" },
    { id: "outgoing", name: "resources.invoices.types.outgoing" }
];`